# parents might me getting Divorced

Tags: parents, divorce

I've just found out that one of my parents want a divorce.

They don't know that I know.

I am a young teen (about15) what should I do?

Comment: We can't really answer that, because there are lots of things you might do and we can't cover them all. It would help if you wrote a bit more. What do you want? What are you afraid of? Which country are you in? Does your other parent know about this? Any siblings? Edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing, no matter how you feel, is don’t take sides... You are not the referee.

Have a relationship with both of them and remember : it is not your fault.

Some will downvote this but it is for you. Why did I write - I have 3 kids (around your age - 2 above, 1 below) and I am divorced...

Best wishes and have a platonic electronic hug :)

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this? It's good, sensible advice.